# WPF TextBlock Textwrapping Causes Text to be Clipped

Tags: wpf, textblock, word-wrap

I have a WPF TextBlock which is causing the text to be clipped. The resulting text is 2 to 3 lines long. Sometimes the bottom of the first line is clipped.

[image: clipped text]

Following is the XAML. The problem is with the TextBlock:

```
<Grid x:Name="background">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Rectangle Width="24"
    Height="24"
    Margin="10,5"
    Fill="{StaticResource ExclaimationIcon}" />
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
    Margin="5"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Text="{Binding Message}"
    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
<Button Grid.Column="2"
    Margin="5"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Command="{Binding Clear}"
    Padding="3"
    Style="{StaticResource HiddenButtonStyle}"
    Visibility="{Binding AllowedToClear,
    Converter={StaticResource ShowOnTrue}}">
    <Image Width="12" Height="12"
        Source="/AppliancePluginLibrary;component/AdminComponents/Assets/Delete.png" />
</Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you add some screeshot how does the problem looks like?

Comment: I will as soon as I can figure out how. It isn't intuitive...

Comment: The help doesn't tell how. Looks like I can add a link to an image, but I'd have to put it up on the web somewhere...

Comment: Ok, it's up there now...

Comment: Weird. I guess, it's a rendering problem. Can you reproduce problem on other PCs/OS? Is it real PC, or just a virtual machine? Don't you set some render option, i.e. ``UseLayoutRounding``, ``SnapsToDevicePixels``, ...? You can also try to disable hardware acceleration for WPF application.

Comment: It doesn't happen on every machine. It's probably related to the Windows settings. We are only running on Windows 7. The PC that it occurs on is a real machine.

Comment: I'll see about disabling the hardware acceleration for WPF.

Comment: I don't know about the render option. I'll look into that...

Comment: I'm going to try setting the TextOption.TextFormattingMode to Display. This issue is probably caused by device independent rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the TextOption.TextFormattingMode to Display fixed this problem.