# In WPF,UseLayoutRounding="True" causes controls to be clipped

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a code that dynamically creates and populates controls(ComboBox,Button,TextBox) into the UI.They were populating fine

But I needed to add background image for the UI,that was blurry, so I set

```
UserLayoutRounding = True
```

Now, few of the dynamically populated controls are showing clipped in the screen.

[image: Button with the clipped end]

I read this [WPF TextBlock Textwrapping Causes Text to be Clipped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23500188/wpf-textblock-textwrapping-causes-text-to-be-clipped). I guess I have similar problem, is there any property for ComboBox and Button like TextOption.TextFormatting for TextBlock

Note: I set margin of the control as

```
control.Margin =  new Thickness(310.4780282,491.571753,0,0)
```

The above causes clipping whereas

```
control.Margin = new Thickness(310.5296382,491.571753,0,0)
```

appears properly . So only for few values of the margin decimal, it occurs, is there any way to detect the values that will cause clipping and fix it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are your margins non-integral?

Comment: These are autogenerated by a utility that parses the position from svg file

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same problem -- controls were being clipped when `UseLayoutRounding="True"`. In my case, I found that I could avoid the clipping by ensuring that every control has a margin on all four sides.